# OpenCv Error: Assertion failed while calling cv::cv2eigen()

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

I have a vector of 2d points `<cv::Point2f>` that I want to convert them to an `Eigen` matrix. Later I want to use it to compute EigenVectors and EigenValues. Here is the code I currently have:

```
// converting vector of <cv::Pointt2f> to cv::Mat
const cv::Mat pts_2d_mat = cv::Mat(pts_2d); 

// create destination Eigen matrix
Eigen::MatrixXf pts_2d_eigen;

// convert cv::Mat to Eigen::Mat
cv::cv2eigen(pts_2d_mat, pts_2d_eigen);
```

But when I run it, it gives me this error:

```
error: (-215) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function copyTo
```

What am I missing?

Comment: floats (`f`) are 32 bit, doubles (`d`) are 64 bit. they are not the same. consider if that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, the issue was the type, I fixed it but now it gives me another error: `error: (-215) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function copyTo`, the input OpenCV matrix has 2 channels, how can I convert it to `Eigen::Mat`?

Comment: If you have a multichannel `Mat`, you may need to convert it to an `Eigen::Tensor`: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/daf/group__core__eigen.html#gaa79981ae2c2dbeea3ccf788d3a851a74. But if you originally had a `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` you could directly get an `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix2Xf>` from that. Please post a [mre].